# Regular site Down table design

Tags: php

I have table called site_down. There I have the following fields values.

```
Day_of_month_from   Day_of_month_to Month_Flag
1                        10           N
5                         7           N
7                        25           N
20                       10           Y
20                       25           Y
```

Detail:

regularly site will down as mentioned below

Every month 1 to 10
Every month 5 to 7
Every month 7 to 25
Every month 20 to 10 and its Month_Flag flag is Y. That is site should down From 20 to next month 10. that is, End of the month and starting of the next month.

Month_Flag flag is N meaning. site down will be in the same month.

How to write PHP logic to push site into down when the date falls between two months.

I have tried below logic.

When the Month_Flag flag is Y , then I take from date and use date('t) to get the end of the month. so I cannot depend the next/To date field but when the next month comes, how to check the condition? How to define the rule?

Note:
Surely few of you will not understand. I will update my question on request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand fully your requirement, but let me try.

So the problem is how to determine the end date of *down site* depending on the flag Y/N.

Say we start from Ds day, M month of Y year, end De

```
start_down = date(Y,M,Ds)

if (flag is Y OR Ds > De) {
  M = M+1
}
if (M > 12) {
  Y = Y+1
  M = 1
}

end_down = date(Y,M,De)
```

Something like that?